# Using a relative clause

Tags: sentence-construction, relative-clauses

Is the following right construction?

> The one who treats you unfairly, tolerate him.

I think this is not accurate. The reason is, as I believe, that the first subject 'the one' has no verb in the predicate. So the right way should be:

> Tolerate him who treats you unfairly.

Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

**The one who treats you unfairly, tolerate him.**

Firstly it is a quotation and quite famous, in fact so famous I cannot remember from where (red face) but I suspect it is biblical. Therefore it can and is written as seen.

---

Secondly

Subject and Predicate Example:

**Ivan jumped.**

In this example, “Ivan” is the subject and “jumped” is the verb. “Jumped” is the predicate of the sentence.

**Ivan read a book to the students**. In this example the meaning is Ivan, who read a book to the students.
In this example, the predicate of the sentence is **“read a book to the students.**” This is what Ivan does

Therefore,

The one (subject) who treats (verb) you unfairly, "**treats you unfairly**" is the predicate. This is what "the one does"

Ref "Writing Explained" [What is a Predicate?](https://writingexplained.org/grammar-dictionary/predicate)